# Reboot remote computer using java

Tags: java, rmi, restart

I want to reboot a computer that is connected with network by RMI,(Remote computer)
Is there any way of doing that ?

And the other question is;

I have a remote computer that is power off. I know ip of that. And I want to start up it.
Is it possible with java ?

Thanks,

Comment: usefull info http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-remotely-turn-on-computer-from-lan-and-wan/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is OS of remote machine?

if windows `shutdown -r` will do.

Answer (score 2):

A computer that's powered off doesn't have an IP address, because it's not connected to any network. So you can't tell it to do anything remotely.

If the computer in question is a server that has an [IPMI interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) that's always powered on even if the server isn't, then you have to find out what protocol the IPMI interface uses (many use ssh) and how to tell it to power the server on.